# ORDER BY # of rows with same option ID from different table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I've made a voting script which already works, but I wanted to practice some MySQL to try and do sorting/filtering of the results via SQL queries instead of getting an entire table as an array and working with that using loops.

I've ran into an issue with sorting the options of a vote based on the amount of times it was voted on. My DB has 3 tables related to this script:

- `vote_votes` - which contains the cast votes, one row per vote cast
- `vote_options` - which contains the possible options for every vote
- `vote_list` - which contains the list of votes with title, type etc.

My original script just got all the options that matched the currently visited vote's ID using

```
SELECT * FROM vote_options WHERE vote_options.vid = $voteID
```

then counted the rows matching the option's unique ID inside `vote_votes` in an array, then sorted it based on the amount of rows with a custom sorting function.

I want to do the same in **one** query, and I think it's possible, I just don't know how. Here's my current `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT
    options.optid as id,
    options.value as value
FROM vote_options options
WHERE vid = {$vote['vid']};");
```

Basically, inside `vote_votes`, each entry has a unique `entryid` and an `optid` column, and I want to add it to the query in a way that these entries are counted as `WHERE vote_votes.optid = options.optid` (Option IDs are unique, so no need to also look for vote ID).

I was hoping this would work, but it's obviously wrong. This is the closest I got before giving up and asking a question here.

```
SELECT
    options.optid as id,
    options.value as value
FROM vote_options options
WHERE vid = {$vote['vid']}
ORDER BY (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM vote_votes
    WHERE vote_votes.optid = options.optid
) DESC;
```

Comment: It`s not clear what you want,but maybe `ORDER BY CASE WHEN vote_options.field=somevalue AND vote_otions.someotherfiled=ithasthisoption THEN..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, it was just a matter of moving the `SELECT` in brackets to the correct place:

```
SELECT
    options.optid as id,
    options.value as value,
    options.vid as voteid,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM vote_votes votes
        WHERE votes.optid = options.optid
    ) as votes
FROM vote_options options
WHERE options.vid = {$vote['vid']}
ORDER BY votes DESC;
```